# How to switch to a "for" loop from an if/else statement?

Tags: python

So currently I have a list of commands and each of them plays out like this:

```
if upp == "help":
        help()
    elif upp == "showdate":
        showdate()
    elif upp == "calculator":
        calculatorb()
    elif upp == "quit":
        quit()
    else:
        print(cmderror)
```

It reads from a list such as:

```
cmds = {
        "help",
        "calculator",
        "showdate",
        "quit"
    }
```

So if a user inputs a command that is not in `cmds` it throws an error alright.

How do I switch to a `for` statement?

First thing I did was make a dict:

```
cmds = {
        "help" : help(),
        "calculator": calculatorb(),
        "showdate" : showdate(),
        "quit" : quit()
    }
```

But now I can't get to implement the `for` statement.

```
for cmds_names, cmds in cmds.items():
        print("E")
```

For some reason all the commands are executed all at once in order by the dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dictionary should contain the functions, not *calls* to the functions.  Remove the `()` from the dictionary values:

```
cmds = {
    "help": help,
    "calculator": calculatorb,
    "showdate": showdate,
    "quit": quit,
}
```

Now you can turn your `if/elif/else` into a simple dictionary lookup:

```
try:
    cmds[upp]()
except KeyError:
    print(cmderror)
```

or:

```
def print_cmd_error():
    print(cmderror)

cmds.get(upp, default=print_cmd_error)()
```

Comment: And the dict should then be used via `cmds[upp]()`